# Google cloud CDN, performance testing using apache benchmark

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, apachebench, google-cdn

I have been serving static files from my NodeJS application deployed on Google App Engine, I have now setup a Google Cloud load balancer (GCLB) with CDN enabled and have moved my static files into a cloud bucket used at the backend.

The whole process works fine, however the issue is that the performance has not improved when testing using Apache Benchmark.

Testing 1000 requests, with 100 concurrency level:

```
Document Length:        748366 bytes

Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   37.069 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        1
   (Connect: 0, Receive: 0, Length: 1, Exceptions: 0)
Total transferred:      748686041 bytes
HTML transferred:       747940252 bytes
Requests per second:    26.98 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       3706.873 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       37.069 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          19723.87 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0  446 748.1    261    9033
Processing:   397 2920 2407.1   2252   17769
Waiting:       31   85 109.7     56    1595
Total:        444 3366 2578.2   2665   18986

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%   2665
  66%   3702
  75%   4410
  80%   4937
  90%   6504
  95%   8125
  98%  10853
  99%  13447
 100%  18986 (longest request)
```

Testing 1000 requests, with 10 concurrency level:

```
Document Length:        748366 bytes

Concurrency Level:      10
Time taken for tests:   35.386 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      749112083 bytes
HTML transferred:       748366000 bytes
Requests per second:    28.26 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       353.863 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       35.386 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          20673.37 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:       20   74  96.3     41     757
Processing:    98  278 159.5    240    2165
Waiting:       30   59  67.0     49    1915
Total:        135  352 196.6    290    2201

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%    290
  66%    334
  75%    381
  80%    442
  90%    577
  95%    742
  98%    935
  99%   1152
 100%   2201 (longest request)
```

I would not expect the concurrency level to dramatically increase the time taken to process requests. Maybe I am somehow misreading these results?

The other (related) issue to note is that CDN cache hits are shown as 0 in the Google LB UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your files aren't being cached. Cloud CDN caches only responses that satisfy the criteria listed at [cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/caching#cacheability](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/caching#cacheability). You can use the troubleshooting steps at [cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/troubleshooting#responses-not-cached](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/troubleshooting#responses-not-cached) to identify the specific issue. If that doesn't help, I'd be happy to take a look if you share a specific URL.

As you probably know, `ab` isn't the most realistic way to assess CDN performance, and you'll run into bottlenecks on your local machine long before you hit any bottlenecks in Cloud CDN itself. If you do use `ab`, make sure to specify the `-k` option. If you don't, you can run out of ephemeral ports.

Comment: Sorry for the double comment, but I have managed to update the metadata on the object `cache-control: public, max-age=2592000` should this now be all good?

Comment: I see that the URL you mentioned now returns a `Cache-Control: public,max-age=3600` header and, when I request the file repeatedly, an `Age` header that indicates the response was served from cache. Hopefully the new `Cache-Control` header resulted in a performance improvement.

Comment: Thanks @elving I will mark your answer as accepted, however do you know a better way to test CDN performance?

Comment: You can test it without and with Cloud CDN enabled. This will allow you to compare results. There is many different tools available in the market to perform such test and you can follow the example explained here:
https://geekflare.com/google-cloud-cdn-test/